# pip using out of date package index

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am trying to install package inside a docker container(python:rc-slim).

As of now I see that most recent azureml-core wheel uploaded to PyPI is:

> azureml_core-1.13.0-py3-none-any.whl

but when I run `pip install azureml-core==1.13.0` I get following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> azureml-core==1.13.0 (from versions: 0.1.50, 0.1.57, 0.1.58, 0.1.59,
> 0.1.65, 0.1.68, 0.1.74, 0.1.80, 1.0rc83, 1.0rc85, 1.0.2, 1.0.6, 1.0.8, 1.0.10, 1.0.15, 1.0.17, 1.0.17.1, 1.0.18, 1.0.21, 1.0.23, 1.0.30, 1.0.33, 1.0.33.1, 1.0.39, 1.0.41, 1.0.41.1, 1.0.43, 1.0.43.1, 1.0.45, 1.0.48, 1.0.53, 1.0.55, 1.0.57, 1.0.57.1, 1.0.60, 1.0.62, 1.0.62.1, 1.0.65, 1.0.65.1, 1.0.69, 1.0.72, 1.0.74, 1.0.76, 1.0.76.1, 1.0.79, 1.0.81, 1.0.81.1, 1.0.83, 1.0.85, 1.0.85.1, 1.0.85.2, 1.0.85.3, 1.0.85.4, 1.0.85.5, 1.0.85.6, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.1rc0, 1.1.1.1rc0, 1.1.1.2rc0, 1.1.2rc0, 1.1.5, 1.1.5.1, 1.1.5.2, 1.1.5.3, 1.1.5.4, 1.1.5.5, 1.1.5.6, 1.1.5.7)

When installing packages from 'apt-get' I usually have to update the index first but I can't find a comparable command to do that with pip.

Comment: you could wget the package then pip install package.whl

Comment: try `azureml_core` instead of `azureml-core`.

Answer (score 0):

`azureml-core` [version 1.1.5.7](https://pypi.org/project/azureml-core/1.1.5.7/) supports Python 2.7 and 3.4+.

Starting from [version 1.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/azureml-core/1.2.0/) it only supports Python 3.5+.

From your list of versions I can guess you use Python 2.7 or 3.4. To use a later version of `azureml-core` you need a later version of Python.

Answer (score -1):

Two possibilities:

1. the package needs you to use an underscore (since hyphens don't behave) so pip can download it: so run `pip install azureml_core==1.13.0`
2. Run with the `--no-cache-dir` argument, so `pip install --no-cache-dir azureml_core==1.13.0`. This argument forces pip to refresh it's package cache.